# How to show an <UL>?

Tags: css

Situation, such a menu:

```
<ul class="top_right_menu">
    <li class="top_right_submenu"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> LANGUAGES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I hover "LANGUAGES" I need to show up the other :

```
<ul class="hover_top_right_menu">
    <li>ENGLISH</li>
    <li>SPANISH</li>
    <li>RUSSIAN</li>
    <li>GERMAN</li>
</ul>
```

Necessary to make it work on CSS, JQuery or without JavaScript. Here's a version does not work:

```
.hover_top_right_menu {
    display: none;
}
```

It's a wrong line

```
.top_right_submenu: hover, hover_top_right_menu {
    display: visible;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? So we know how to help you.

Comment: Where is your question about programming?

Comment: In your original (unedited) question, there was a space between the full stop (.) and top_right_submenu - if this is in your original code, it's a big part of what's causeing the problem and shouldn't have been edited out - if it's justa  typo in this post then fine.

Comment: @user3309566 is my answer was useful you should mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 4):

You have some typos in your css

by default the element `.hover_top_right_menu` should have `display: none`. When you hover the submenu then you change its display (with `display: block`).

```
.hover_top_right_menu {
    display: none;
}


.top_right_submenu:hover .hover_top_right_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

---

Anyway this css is based on the assumption that the language list is nested into `.hover_top_right_menu` element, e.g.:

```
<ul class="top_right_menu">
    <li class="top_right_submenu"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> LANGUAGES
       <ul class="hover_top_right_menu">
          <li>ENGLISH</li>
          <li>SPANISH</li>
          <li>RUSSIAN</li>
          <li>GERMAN</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

As a side notes:

- Unless you need to have an action on click event, the link around "LANGUAGES" is not necessary for the example
- you're using empty markup, probably for styling purpose only. If you need to have an icon just place it as a background of that list-item (or as `content` property of its `:before` pseudoelement)